# How do you use MAX properly?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query

```
$gethigherrows = "(SELECT *
    FROM highscore 
   WHERE score >= '$score' 
ORDER BY score ASC,
position ASC
   LIMIT 5)";
```

Here is what I want to include:

```
SELECT * FROM highscore WHERE score > '$score' AND position (is the highest 5 numbers of that group)
```

[image]

it's close, but the high scores above the user entry should be 9,8,7,6,5

the problem is the `ORDER BY score ASC` part seems to just pull a random 5 out that have the correct score, I want it to pull the concurrent positions in the high score table

Comment: Maybe you should describe in words what you need. A little description of what 'score' and 'position' contain would help too. And what is a group? As far as I can see now, your current query already does what you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got what I wanted by outputting the results with the highest position number and then using the `array_reverse()` command.

```
     $gethigherrows = "(SELECT *
 FROM highscore
    WHERE score >= '$score'
    ORDER BY position DESC
LIMIT 5)";

$getlowerrows = "(SELECT * 
    FROM highscore 
   WHERE score < '$score'
ORDER BY score DESC, 
position ASC
   LIMIT 5)";

$higherrows= mysql_query($gethigherrows);
$lowerrows= mysql_query($getlowerrows);

if(mysql_error())echo mysql_error();

$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($higherrows)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$revrows = array_reverse($rows);

foreach($revrows as $row) 
{
    $uppertable .= "<tr><td>$row[position]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[score]</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've *almost* got what you want. You just need to tweak the ordering. If you first order by descending `position` values, you'll get the 5 highest numbers.

```
SELECT *
    FROM highscore
    WHERE score > '$score'
    ORDER BY position DESC, score ASC
    LIMIT 5
```

Comment: doesnt give me what I want unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select top 5 from highscores where score > $score order by score desc
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention its MySQL